# What is the difference between the transition matrix of an embedded markov chain, and the transition function?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am currently working through the book Introduction to Stochastic Processes with R by Dobrow, and am confused what the difference between the transition probabilities of an infinitesimal generator matrix, and the entries of the transition **function**. In the book, he denotes that the transition probabilities can be found using the generator matrix in the following way:

He defines $q_i$ as the holding time which is given as 
$$q_i = \displaystyle \sum_{j\neq i}q_{ij}$$ where $i$ and $j$ are states in a continuous time finite state Markov chain, and $q_{ij}$ is the transition *rate* from state $i$ to $j$.

Using this fact, he states that the transition probability $p_{ij} = \frac{q_{ij}}{q_{i}}$, and that the matrix consisting of these probabilities is called the transition matrix for the embedded chain denoted as $\tilde{\mathbf{P}}$

He also states that the transition function of a generator matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ can be found by finding the matrix exponential of $\mathbf{Q}$, given as
$$
\mathbf{P}(t) = e^{t\mathbf{Q}}
$$

What is the difference between $\tilde{\mathbf{P}}$ and $()$ for a continuous time finite state Markov chain, and when should the embedded chain matrix be used over the transition function matrix?

Answer (score 1):

The transition rates $q_{ij}$ determine the time evolution of the process. The embedded chain only records the order in which states are visited. For example, the generator matrix $Q$ satisfies $[e^{tQ}]_{ij} = \mathbb P(X(t)=j\mid X(0)=i)$.  You can think of the embedded chain as a semi-Markov process with holding times identically equal to one.